# Fetching results from database using bind_param, prepare statement and fetch are not working

Tags: php, mysql, object, select, mysqli

please I need help to get the last function to work . The database connection is ok. The  function display_all($id) is not working. It is not displaying the result when i called it as you can see below from the new instant created . Please can someone help me out.  Thanks

```
<?php



    class connect_dbase


    {
        public function connection($host="localhost",$user="root",$password="london",$db_name="users")

        {

            $mysqli=new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db_name);
            if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);

            }
            else 

            {

                echo " Database connection successful";


            }

        }



         public function display_all($id)
    {
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name,email,address FROM user WHERE id =?"))
    {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->num_row() >0)


    {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // do something with $row

        echo $row['name']. $row['email']. $row['address'];
    }  




        }

    else
    {  echo "no result found";}




    }

       else
       {

           echo "cant prepare result";

       }

    }





    }
    $connect_dbase=new connect_dbase();

    $connect_dbase->connection();

    $connect_dbase->display_all(3);






    ?>
```

Comment: Hello, I have modified the code to tis and still now displaying. can soneone help pinpoint hwere the problems may lie.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqli object is not in instance scope, and i don't know why you're not getting any warnings from this. Since you're using it in OO mode, you need to declare it to the class you're using it in so it knows where to go.

```
class connect_dbase {

    private $mysqli;
```

Then in what looks to be the constructor that is creating the connection object.

```
public function connection($host="localhost",$user="root",$password="london",$db_name="users")
{
    $this->mysqli=new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db_name);
//rest of your code
```

And then anywhere else you need to access your mysqli object just call $this->mysqli to get access to it in your instance.

Answer (score 0):

For start you need to declare private or public class variable  $mysqli

```
class connect_dbase {
    private  $mysqli;
...
```

than you use your variable like this:

```
public function display_all($id) {
    if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT...
```

Answer (score 0):

**$mysqli** variable is out of scope to the **display_all** method.
You should use a class variable:

```
class connect_dbase{

    private $mysqli; //Or public/protected

    public function connection($host="localhost",$user="root",$password="london",$db_name="users")
    {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host,....);
        .....
    }

    public function display_all($id)
    {
        if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT name,....);
        ....
    }
```

}